# Fetch all pages using a Python request, using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I tried to fetch all product's name from the web page, but I could have only 12.

If I scroll down the web page then it gets refreshed and adds more information.

How can I to get all information?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

url = "https://www.outre.com/product-category/wigs/"

res = requests.get(url)
res.raise_for_status()

soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")

items = soup.find_all("div", attrs={"class":"title-wrapper"})

for item in items:

  print(item.p.a.get_text())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good. The thing is on the website; the products are dynamically loaded, so when you do your request you can only get the first 12 products.

You can check the developer console inside your browser to track the Ajax call made during browsing.

I did it, and it turns out a call is made to retrieve more product to the URL

https://www.outre.com/product-category/wigs/page/2/

So if you want to get all the products you need to browse multiple pages. I suggest you to use a loop and use your code several times.

N.B.: You can try to check the website to see is there is a more convenient place to get the product (like not from the main page)

Answer (score 0):

The page loads the products from different URL via JavaScript, so Beautiful Soup doesn't see it. To get all pages, you can use the following example:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.outre.com/product-category/wigs/page/{}/"

page = 1
while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content, "html.parser")
    titles = soup.select(".product-title")

    if not titles:
        break

    for title in titles:
        print(title.text)

    page += 1
```

Prints:

```
...

Wet & Wavy Loose Curl 18″
Wet & Wavy Boho Curl 20″
Nikaya
Jeanette
Natural Glam Body
Natural Free Deep
```